# Как улучшить оценочную функцию minimax для сложных крестики-нолики

Tags: python, pygame

Файл main.py

```py
import threading

import pygame as pg
import sys
from game import Game
from minimax import Minimax

pg.init()  # Инициализация Pygame
margin = 5  # Отступ
board_size = 180  # Размер доски
button_size = 55  # Размер кнопки
width = height = board_size * 3 + margin * 4  # Размеры окна
size_window = (width, height)  # Размер окна
screen = pg.display.set_mode(size_window)  # Создание окна
pg.display.set_caption("Сложные крестики нолики")  # Установка заголовка окна

# Цвета
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

game = Game()  # Создание новой игры


def run_minimax(game):  # Функция для запуска алгоритма Minimax
    alg_minimax = Minimax(game, 100)  # Создание экземпляра алгоритма Minimax
    _, best_move = alg_minimax.minimax(0, False, -float('inf'), float('inf'))  # Выполнение алгоритма Minimax
    if best_move is not None:  # Если найден лучший ход
        if game.make_move(alg_minimax.next_game_board, best_move):  # Если ход возможен
            # Вывод информации о сделанном ходе
            print(
                f"Компьютер сделал ход на доске"
                f" {alg_minimax.next_game_board[0] * 3 + alg_minimax.next_game_board[1] + 1} "
                f"в ячейке {best_move[0] + 1}, {best_move[1] + 1}")
            print(f"Следующий ход на доске {game.next_board[0] * 3 + game.next_board[1] + 1}")


def draw_endgame_message(result):  # Функция для отображения сообщения о конце игры
    if result == 'X':
        message = "Победили крестики!"
    elif result == 'O':
        message = "Победили нолики!"
    else:
        message = "Ничья!"
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 50)  # Создание шрифта
    text = font.render(message, True, (0, 0, 0))  # Создание текста
    # Отображение текста в центре экрана
    screen.blit(text, (width // 2 - text.get_width() // 2, height // 2 - text.get_height() // 2))


def reset_game():  # Функция для сброса игры
    global game
    game = Game()  # Создание новой игры



while True:  # Главный цикл игры
    for event in pg.event.get():  # Обработка событий
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit(0)  # Завершение работы программы
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # Если событие - нажатие кнопки мыши
            x, y = pg.mouse.get_pos()  # Получение координат мыши
            board_col = x // board_size  # Определение столбца доски
            board_row = y // board_size  # Определение строки доски
            button_col = (x % board_size) // button_size  # Определение столбца кнопки
            button_row = (y % board_size) // button_size  # Определение строки кнопки
            if game.make_move((board_row, board_col), (button_row, button_col)):  # Если ход возможен
                # Вывод информации о сделанном ходе
                print(f"Ход сделан на доске {board_row * 3 + board_col + 1} в ячейке {button_row + 1},{button_col + 1}")
                print(f"Следующий ход на доске {game.next_board[0] * 3 + game.next_board[1] + 1}")
                if game.current_player == 'O':  # Если текущий игрок - 'O'
                    minimax_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_minimax, args=(game,))  # Создание потока для алгоритма Minimax
                    minimax_thread.start()  # Запуск потока
                    minimax_thread.join()  # Ожидание завершения потока
            if game.game_over():  # Если игра окончена
                result = game.game_over()  # Получение результата игры
                draw_endgame_message(result)  # Отображение сообщения о конце игры
                pg.display.update()  # Обновление дисплея
                pg.time.wait(2000)  # Задержка в 2 секунды
                reset_game()  # Сброс игры
            else:  # Если ход невозможен
                print(f"Ход невозможен")

    font = pg.font.Font(None, 24)  # Создание шрифта
    for board_row in range(3):  # Для каждой строки доски
        for board_col in range(3):  # Для каждого столбца доски
            for row in range(3):  # Для каждой строки клетки
                for col in range(3):  # Для каждого столбца клетки
                    x = (col * button_size + (col + 1) * margin) + (
                            board_col * (board_size + margin))  # Вычисление координаты x клетки
                    y = (row * button_size + (row + 1) * margin) + (
                            board_row * (board_size + margin))  # Вычисление координаты y клетки
                    cell_row = row % 3  # Определение строки клетки
                    cell_col = col % 3  # Определение столбца клетки
                    symbol = game.board[board_row][board_col][cell_row][cell_col]  # Получение символа клетки
                    if symbol == 'X':  # Если символ - 'X'
                        color = GREEN  # Цвет клетки - зеленый
                    elif symbol == 'O':  # Если символ - 'O'
                        color = RED  # Цвет клетки - красный
                    else:  # Если клетка пуста
                        color = WHITE  # Цвет клетки - белый
                    pg.draw.rect(screen, color, (x, y, button_size, button_size))  # Отрисовка клетки
                    if symbol != '_':  # Если клетка не пуста
                        font = pg.font.Font(None, 36)  # Создание шрифта
                        text = font.render(symbol, True, BLACK)  # Создание текста
                        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(x + button_size // 2, y + button_size // 2))  # Создание прямоугольника для текста
                        screen.blit(text, text_rect)  # Отрисовка текста
    pg.display.update()  # Обновление дисплея
```

Файл game.py

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [[[['_'] * 3 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]  # Инициализация доски игры
        self.current_player = 'X'  # Установка текущего игрока
        self.next_board = None  # Установка следующей доски

    def make_move(self, board, cell):  # Функция для выполнения хода
        board_row, board_col = board  # Получение координат доски
        button_row, button_col = cell  # Получение координат клетки
        # Проверка, можно ли сделать ход на данной доске
        if self.next_board is not None and self.next_board != (board_row, board_col):
            return False
        try:
            # Проверка, свободна ли клетка
            if self.board[board_row][board_col][button_row][button_col] != '_':
                return False
            # Выполнение хода
            self.board[board_row][board_col][button_row][button_col] = self.current_player
            self.next_board = (button_row, button_col)
            # Переключение игрока
            self.current_player = 'O' if self.current_player == 'X' else 'X'
            return True
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def check_winner(self, player):  # Функция для проверки, выиграл ли игрок
        for board_row in range(3):
            for board_col in range(3):
                for i in range(3):
                    # Проверка строк и столбцов на выигрыш
                    if self.board[board_row][board_col][i][0] == self.board[board_row][board_col][i][1] == \
                            self.board[board_row][board_col][i][2] == player:
                        return True
                    if self.board[board_row][board_col][0][i] == self.board[board_row][board_col][1][i] == \
                            self.board[board_row][board_col][2][i] == player:
                        return True
                # Проверка диагоналей на выигрыш
                if self.board[board_row][board_col][0][0] == self.board[board_row][board_col][1][1] == \
                        self.board[board_row][board_col][2][2] == player:
                    return True
                if self.board[board_row][board_col][0][2] == self.board[board_row][board_col][1][1] == \
                        self.board[board_row][board_col][2][0] == player:
                    return True
        return False

    def game_over(self):  # Функция для проверки, окончена ли игра
        # Проверяем, выиграл ли кто-нибудь
        if self.check_winner('X'):
            return 'X'
        if self.check_winner('O'):
            return 'O'
        # Проверяем, есть ли еще доступные ходы
        for board_row in range(3):
            for board_col in range(3):
                for button_row in range(3):
                    for button_col in range(3):
                        if self.board[board_row][board_col][button_row][button_col] == '_':
                            return None
        # Если ни один из игроков не выиграл и нет доступных ходов, игра закончена
        return 'Draw'
```

файл minimax.py

```py
class Minimax:
    def __init__(self, game, max_depth):
        self.game_boards = game.board  # Инициализация доски игры
        self.next_game_board = game.next_board  # Инициализация следующей доски
        self.max_depth = max_depth  # Установка максимальной глубины
        self.start_time = time.time()  # Установка начального времени

    def evaluate(self, player, depth):  # Функция оценки
        score = 0  # Инициализация счета
        opponent = 'O' if player == 'X' else 'X'  # Определение противника

        for board_row in range(3):  # Для каждой строки доски
            for board_col in range(3):  # Для каждого столбца доски
                for i in range(3):  # Для каждой строки клетки
                    # Проверяем строки и столбцы
                    for line in [self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i],
                                 [self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][j][i] for j in range(3)]]:
                        if line.count(player) == 2 and line.count('_') == 1:
                            score += 10 / depth  # Близость к победе
                        if line.count(opponent) == 2 and line.count('_') == 1:
                            score -= 20 / depth  # Угроза

                # Проверяем диагонали
                for diag in [[self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][i] for i in range(3)],
                             [self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][2 - i] for i in range(3)]]:
                    if diag.count(player) == 2 and diag.count('_') == 1:
                        score += 30 / depth  # Близость к победе
                    if diag.count(opponent) == 2 and diag.count('_') == 1:
                        score -= 20 / depth  # Угроза

                # Центральные клетки
                if self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][1][1] == player:
                    score += 1

                # Угловые клетки
                for i, j in [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]:
                    if self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] == player:
                        score += 1

                # Блокирование противника
                for i in range(3):
                    for j in range(3):
                        if self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] == player and any(
                                line.count(opponent) == 1 and line.count('_') == 2 for line in
                                [self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i],
                                 [self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][k][j] for k in range(3)],
                                 [self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][k][k] for k in range(3)],
                                 [self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][k][2 - k] for k in range(3)]]):
                            score += 5  # Блокирование противника

        return score, None  # Возвращение оценки

    def minimax(self, depth, isMaximizing, alpha, beta):
        # Если достигнута максимальная глубина или превышено время, возвращаем оценку текущего состояния игры
        if depth == self.max_depth or time.time() - self.start_time > 10:
            return self.evaluate('X' if isMaximizing else 'O', depth)

        board_row, board_col = self.next_game_board  # Получаем координаты следующей доски

        if isMaximizing:  # Если текущий игрок максимизирует оценку
            best = -1000  # Инициализация лучшего значения
            best_move = None  # Инициализация лучшего хода

            for i in range(3):  # Перебор всех клеток на доске
                for j in range(3):
                    if self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] == '_':  # Если клетка свободна
                        self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] = 'X'  # Совершаем ход
                        original_next_board = self.next_game_board  # Сохраняем оригинальную следующую доску
                        self.next_game_board = (i, j)  # Обновляем следующую доску
                        score, _ = self.minimax(depth + 1, not isMaximizing, alpha, beta)  # Рекурсивный вызов minimax
                        self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] = '_'  # Отменяем ход
                        self.next_game_board = original_next_board  # Восстанавливаем следующую доску

                        if score > best:  # Если новый счет лучше предыдущего лучшего
                            best = score  # Обновляем лучший счет
                            best_move = (i, j)  # Обновляем лучший ход

                        alpha = max(alpha, best)  # Обновляем значение alpha
                        if beta <= alpha:  # Если beta меньше или равно alpha, прерываем цикл
                            break

            return best, best_move  # Возвращаем лучший счет и лучший ход

        else:  # Если текущий игрок минимизирует оценку
            best = 1000  # Инициализация лучшего значения
            best_move = None  # Инициализация лучшего хода

            for i in range(3):  # Перебор всех клеток на доске
                for j in range(3):
                    if self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] == '_':  # Если клетка свободна
                        self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] = 'O'  # Совершаем ход
                        original_next_board = self.next_game_board  # Сохраняем оригинальную следующую доску
                        self.next_game_board = (i, j)  # Обновляем следующую доску
                        score, _ = self.minimax(depth + 1, not isMaximizing, alpha, beta)  # Рекурсивный вызов minimax
                        self.game_boards[board_row][board_col][i][j] = '_'  # Отменяем ход
                        self.next_game_board = original_next_board  # Восстанавливаем следующую доску

                        if score < best:  # Если новый счет лучше предыдущего лучшего
                            best = score  # Обновляем лучший счет
                            best_move = (i, j)  # Обновляем лучший ход

                        beta = min(beta, best)  # Обновляем значение beta
                        if beta <= alpha:  # Если beta меньше или равно alpha, прерываем цикл
                            break

            return best, best_move  # Возвращаем лучший счет и лучший ход
```

Написал сложную версию крестики-нолики.

Игра состоит из 9 досок, каждая из которых имеет размер 3х3. Это создает дополнительный уровень сложности по сравнению с классической игрой в крестики-нолики.

Игроки ходят по очереди, ставя свой символ (крестик или нолик) в свободную ячейку на одной из досок. Первый игрок может сделать ход на любой доске. После этого следующий ход должен быть сделан на доске, которая соответствует ячейке, выбранной в предыдущем ходе. Например, если первый игрок сделал ход в центральной ячейке на одной из досок, следующий ход должен быть сделан на центральной доске.

Бот реализован с помощью алгоритма minimax с альфа бета отсечением, но вот в чём проблема, это функция оценки, вроде все варианты перебрал, но хз какие оценки ставить для непобедимого бота, помогите пожалуйста